# selenium web driver sendKeys in a loop java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

How should I use `sendKeys` in loop? First time sendKeys work correct, but second time, on the new page - exception.

```
public class main {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\asdasd\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.kommersant.ru");
            Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true) {
                WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".search__input"));
               // WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".search__button"));
                String s = scanner.nextLine();

                if(s.equals("exit")){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
                    search.sendKeys(s);
                    WebElement searchButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".search__button")));
                    searchButton.click();
                    searchButton.click();
                }

            }
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

[image: First query hockey work correctly]
[image: Second query footbal error]

Comment: Could you please give us some info on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you please post the actual text of the error message? That screenshot is impossible to read on my display.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your loop condition right.The problem lies there.

Comment: and also if you could elaborate on what you are trying to do, then that would be helpful.